# Run methods in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making an animation. I'm generating a bunch of images and I want to add these to a gif encoder. As the process of adding might take quite some time, I want this to be done in a separate thread. My idea would be to do this:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();

    public void run() {
        encoder.start("MyFile.gif");
    }

    public void addFrame(BufferedImage img) {
        encoder.add(img);
    }

}
```

Then I would call the `addFrame()` method from the main class every time a frame needs to be added. However, when I gave it a second thought, I concluded that this is not how it works.

Another idea is to create a new thread object for every time a frame is added:

```
public class MyMainClass {
    while (generating) {
        BufferedImage img = generateImg();

        new Thread(() -> {
            encoder.addFrame(img);
        }).start();
    }
}
```

However, to me this seems like a very heavy way to do this.

**My question:** what is a better way to achieve this? If there is not, is the idea of creating a new `Thread` object really that heavy?

Comment: About your first idea:  Your `MyThread` class is _not_ a thread.  It's just a class with methods named `run()` and `addFrame(...)`.  When your program executes `new Thread(myThread).start()`, the new thread will call `myThread.run()`.  And if your main thread later calls `myThread.addFrame(...)`, well, that happens _in the main thread_, and _not_ in the new thread.

Comment: @jameslarge I forgot to specify I would do that. Anyway, thanks for confirming that it wouldn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ExecutorService

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

es.submit(() -> encoder.start("MyFile.gif"));

es.submit(() -> encoder.addFrame(img));
```

Answer (score 1):

**About your first idea**

Your `MyThread` class is not a thread. It's just a class with methods named `run()` and `addFrame(...)`. When your program executes the following, The run method will be called in the new thread:

```
MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
new Thread(myThread).start();
```

But, if your main thread later calls `myThread.addFrame(...)`, that happens *in the main thread*.  You can't write code that calls a method in another thread.  Method calls happen in the thread that does the call.  Always.

**About your second idea**

You're right.  It's heavy-weight.  Creating new threads is expensive.  That's one reason why *thread pools* were invented.  (See Peter Lawrey's answer)

The other reason thread pools were invented is to let your program manage the number of threads doing work at any given time.  Nothing stops the main thread in your second example from creating a hundred new worker threads, or ten thousand, or...  One after another.

With a thread pool, the threads are de-coupled from the work that they do.  You can give the thread pool ten-thousand jobs to do, but it may only use ten threads to do them.  Depends how the thread pool is configured.

The one in Peter Lawrey's example is configured to use just one worker thread.

Other methods of the `java.util.concurrent.Executors` class will create differently configured thread pools for you, or you can configure something even more sophisticated by explicitly constructing and configuring a `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extra explanation. One more question: you say all the action is done in one worker thread. Does this mean that every job it's given is executed one after the other, in the order they are submitted?

Comment: @Creator13, Yes.  A thread pool has a blocking queue for tasks, and it has some (possibly variable) number of worker threads.  Worker threads loop forever, picking tasks off the queue, and running them.  If the queue gets empty, the workers are blocked until more tasks are added.  A fancy thread pool (e.g., `ThreadPoolExecutor`) may kill off some workers if the queue is empty for long enough, or add some workers if the queue is too full for too long.  The one returned by `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` just has one worker that performs tasks strictly in the order they were added.